# Zoom image returns to 1:1 if UIButton image is changed

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have a UIButton for brush, and another for zoom.

If I keep the images the same, both work well.
The images are attached to the buttons in Interface Builder:

[image]

If I change the button image for "draw", after a zoom action, the image will return to no zoom.

```
drawButton.setImage(UIImage.init(named: "Brush.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
```

How can I change the image without affecting the zoom -- I want to be able to draw in a zoomed mode.

I have tried something like this:

```
drawButton.imageView?.image = UIImage.init(named: "BrushYellow.png")
```

This does not affect the zoom, but does not change the image. Ideas welcome please.

Comment: I tend to use the background image and force an aspect ratio equal to the aspect of the image on my buttons. It prevents all the pesky issues that come like what you are referring to.

Comment: hmm, I just tried using a background image only, but I get the same issue -- I'm forced to set a UIControlState value and zooming goes wonky. I may have to only use a changing background color.

Comment: @Sethmr, I may be getting somewhere.. If I set the button with no default image, and then set the background image with pattern.. image, the it may work. How do I set the aspect so that it fits the button size .. just use .frame? Thanks!

Comment: I just look at the actual aspect of the photo and set the constraint on the storyboard with an aspect ratio of the images dimensions. If you are creating it programmatically, then frame should work as well. Make sure you are using 'UIButton().setBackgroundImage(image: UIImage?, for: UIControlState) ' or you will have overlapping images.

Comment: Would you write this as an answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to use the background image and force an aspect ratio equal to the aspect of the image on my buttons. It prevents all the pesky issues that come like what you are referring to.

Look at the actual aspect of the photo and set the constraint on the storyboard with an aspect ratio of the images dimensions. If you are creating it programmatically, then setting the frame with the ratio should work as well. Make sure you are using

```
UIButton().setBackgroundImage(image: UIImage?, for: UIControlState)
```

for changing the image or you will have overlapping images. If you need to set it for multiple control states, then do so, but I rarely find this necessary for anything other than .Normal

If you need to change the constraint then you can create an outlet to it and change its multiplier from 1:1 to whatever it should be and back. If the UI doesn't update itself you may need to call `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()`

Comment: Thanks!. But if I use the setBackgroundImage:for:UIControlState, I get the same pesky behavior as if I was just using setImage:: Up voted, as you got me thinking about UIBackgroundColor and whether I can add an image to that..

Comment: Use the constraint thing. Adding an image as a color is a lot more work than it is worth, and I doubt will change the problem you are faced with.